# Why is my driven dimension affecting my sketch AutoDesk Inventor

Tags: design, computer-aided-design, autodesk-inventor

I am making a parameter defined sketch that can be changed by editing a few values.
When i was doing some math i created a driven dimension to make sure that i was getting the correct value.

For some reason the driven dimension creates an error in my sketch despite never being referenced in any calculations.

Here I have a dimension that is supposed to be 35 in at all angles(currently 30degrees).
[image: 30 degrees]

If i change the angle it has a small error.

[image: error after change]

But if i delete the driven dimension and put it back it no longer has any error.
[image: Corrected dimension]

I don't know why this is happening and now i don't know if i can trust driven dimensions as references.
Does anyone know why this is happening and if its something i can fix without deleting and recreating dimensions every time i make a change?

Comment: What happens if you update or rebuild it, without deleting/re-adding? - see https://i.imgur.com/llGwRII.png

Comment: Nothing, the button is grayed out. The only way to fix it is by deleting and readding.

Comment: Both buttons are greyed out, even when you exit the sketch edit environment?

Comment: Note how the other values in your screenshots are also changing between the screenshots - the reference dimension is showing the true distance between those points. It looks like you have a chain of equations that are not updating in you way you expect - possibly there is some kind of circular reference?

Comment: All of my dimensions are driven off of equations that only take user parameters as inputs.
Is it possible that my constrains are to blame? I noticed that if you have conflicting constraints that it tries to do both by going half way.

Comment: Yes - that could be a possible cause. It's impossible to say for sure from the information available to me, though.